# It is not possible to output data from MySQL (Wordpress)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I use a Wordpress site, I do my search on a custom database called "operations". The search is performed on the website.
I need to get other results from the table related to this row on request, not just what I entered. And get other data related to this string. Here is the search form on the site:

```
    <form method="post" action="https://site-name.com/wp-content/themes/theme/select_user.php">
    <label for="sku">SKU:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="sku" size="30"><br/>
    <label for="barcode">Barcode:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="barcode" size="30"><br/>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search"><br/>
    </form>
    </fieldset>
```

The database has the following columns: id, date, title, size, sku, barcode, price

File Contents select_user.php:

```
require( __DIR__ . '/../../../wp-load.php' );

global $wpdb;


$sku = trim($_REQUEST['sku']);
$barcode = trim($_REQUEST['barcode']);


$sql_select = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "operations 
    WHERE sku='$sku' || barcode='$barcode',
    ARRAY_N
    "
    )
);  


if ($sql_select)
{
    foreach($sql_select as $row)
    {
        echo 'SKU: ' . $row['sku'] .'</br>';
        echo 'Barcode: ' . $row['barcode'] .'</br>';
    }
        
}
else {
    echo 'No results';
    }
```

With this code, I get the answer "no results".
I would be grateful for any help

Comment: you only did prepare you also need to use execute ,besides that your code is prone to SQLinjections

Comment: @Raymond Nijland , I once read on the forum that $wpdb->prepare helps protect against SQL injection...

Comment: Hi! I'm glad you solved your problem. The convention on this site is to keep Questions and Answers separate, so you are encouraged to answer your own question in the box below, rather than editing a solution into the question. You can then tick the answer as "accepted", and the question will be shown as "answered" in search results etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my own shortcode, and placed everything that is necessary there. Everything works.

```
function custom_search_func( $atts ){
    
    echo '<fieldset>
    <form action="' . get_permalink() . '" method="POST">
    <label for="sku">SKU:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="sku" size="30"><br/>
    <label for="barcode">Barcode:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="barcode" size="30"><br/>
    <label for="date">Date:</label><br/>
    <input type="date" name="date" size="30"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    </fieldset>';

    global $wpdb;
    $sku = trim($_REQUEST['sku']);
    $barcode = trim($_REQUEST['barcode']);
    $date = trim($_REQUEST['date']);
    

$sql_select = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
    "
    SELECT id, date, title, size, barcode, sku, price FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "operations 
    WHERE sku='$sku' || barcode='$barcode' || date='$date'
    "
    )
);  



if ($sql_select)
{
    echo '<table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5">';
    echo '<tr><th>ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Title</th>';
    echo '<th>Size</th>';
    echo '<th>SKU</th>';
    echo '<th>Barcode</th>';
    echo '<th>Price</th>';
    echo '<th>Date</th></tr>';
    foreach ( $sql_select as $id) {
        
        
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $id->id;
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $id->title;
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $id->size;
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $id->sku;
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $id->barcode;
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $id->price;
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo $id->date;
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        
    }
        echo '</table>';
        
}
else {
    echo 'No results';
    }
    
}
 
add_shortcode( 'customsearch', 'custom_search_func' );
```

Use the [customsearch] shortcode to output this anywhere on the page

Answer (score 1):

use the post hook for wp forms not directly use .php file

```
add_action( 'admin_post_add_foobar', 'prefix_admin_add_foobar' );
function prefix_admin_add_foobar() {
    // Handle request then generate response using echo or leaving PHP and using HTML
}
```

for your form use :

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-post.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add_foobar">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="foobarid">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I have already fixed this, however I can't figure out how I can output other values from the database.

Comment: if use get_results  set output type as OBJECT in last param